# Change line thickness of gtk_render_line

Tags: gtk3

I'd like to use `gtk_render_line` instead of `cairo_line_to`.

I've replaced the calls but kept `cairo_set_line_width(cc,2)` and the lines have changed to 1px wide.

Because gtk_render_line uses the style context, I guess I have to set a CSS property that will control that.

What is the name of the property that controls the line thickness rendered by gtk_render_line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source of [`gtk_render_line`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkrender.c?h=3.20.4#n602) the actual drawing is done by [`gtk_do_render_line`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkrender.c?h=3.20.4#n563), the source of which looks like this:

```
gtk_do_render_line (GtkStyleContext *context,
                    cairo_t         *cr,
                    gdouble          x0,
                    gdouble          y0,
                    gdouble          x1,
                    gdouble          y1)
{
  const GdkRGBA *color;

  cairo_save (cr);

  color = _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba (_gtk_style_context_peek_property (context, GTK_CSS_PROPERTY_COLOR));

  cairo_set_line_cap (cr, CAIRO_LINE_CAP_SQUARE);
  cairo_set_line_width (cr, 1);    /* <----------------- Relevant for this question */

  cairo_move_to (cr, x0 + 0.5, y0 + 0.5);
  cairo_line_to (cr, x1 + 0.5, y1 + 0.5);

  gdk_cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, color);
  cairo_stroke (cr);

  cairo_restore (cr);
}
```

In here we can see that the width of the line is not determined by any CSS attribute, it is just fixed to a width of `1`. So there is no attribute or other way to change it directly within Gtk...